# How to get the parent of a menu item?

Tags: android

In my click listener

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

How can I find the parent menu of a item? I want to be able to go through each item of the menu which contains item and change its child elements.
So far I can only determine the group it is in

```
    int groupid = item.getGroupId();
    if (groupid == R.id.group1) {

    }
```

Thanks